# How to permanently remove inbuilt apps from pop os?

Tags: gnome, uninstall, reinstall

When I use sudo apt autoremove to uninstall inbuilt gnome apps like seahorse(password manager), gnome-calendar, gnome-weather, gnome-contacts, they successfully uninstall. But after sometime, in notification area, I see an update, and after updating, all these apps are back again.

Is there a way to remove these permanently ,without them being reinstalled again and again.

Comment: Try this: https://support.system76.com/articles/desktop-environment/  and install Xfce as a desktop. Xfce is the best Linux desktop I have used. You need to combine uninstallation of Gnome with another desktop of your choice so that you have a desktop when you restart.

Comment: @John like the Gnome desktop on Ubuntu, why doesnt popOS Gnome allow to uninstall the packages? Because in the end both are GNOME desktop environment.

Comment: I have Gnome in Ubuntu and simply ignore what I do not need.  I have Xfce in Kali and work more in Kali than in Ubuntu but in either case just ignore what I do not need. In the above link, Mate is a decent desktop that would be familiar to you.